# How to Send CSRF token to ajax request Using Django?

Tags: python, django

i Want to Send csrf token in Ajax Request in Django.i don't know how to do that .i have following Code.

in My html File, i am having one button

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-right" id="button_div">
            <a href="#" id="add_data" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
    </div>

    <div id="dynamic_table">
      /*some html*/
    </div>
```

When i Click on "Add" button,i  Empty "dynamic_table" and i  Append my contact form code into "dynamic_table" div.
Contact Form code is

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="fname">
   <input type="text" name="lname">
   <input type="button" name="send" value="send">
</form>
```

for that i am Using following Code

```
$(document).on('click','#add_data',function(){
    $("#dynamic_table").empty();
    $("#dynamic_table").append('<form><input type="text" name="fname"><input type="text" name="lname"><input type="button" name="send" id="form_save" value="send"></form>');
});
```

till now, its working fine but When i Click on "form_save" button from my contact form

```
$(document).on('click','#save_btn',function(){
alert('hello')
})
```

i am Getting following Error

```
 Forbidden (403)
    CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
    
In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template's render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.
You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

i am new in Django.any help will be Appreciated

Comment: Can you share how you are making the `ajax` call. In the headers we can send the csrf token.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could place your form inside the div.#dynamic_table as a normal form but make it invisiblem and the JS part just makes it visible again and submit it. This way, I think your can get back the {% csrf_token %} to the template and there is no csrf issue.